# Ruby: else without rescue is useless

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I'm new to ruby.  I'm trying to write an apache error.log monitor.  It is mostly done, but I'm getting the warning: else without rescue is useless.
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Does Ruby want me to use a 'unless'?

```
class ErrorMonitor
   @@previous_size=0
   @@counter=0

   def initialize()
   end

   def process
    if @@counter > 0
       @new_size= File.stat('/var/log/apache2/error.log').size
       if @new_size > @@previous_size
          for i in @@previous_size..@new_size - @@previous_size
             print IO.readlines("/var/log/apache2/error.log")[i]
          end
          @@previous_size = @new_size
       end
    end
    else
       @@previous_size= File.stat('/var/log/apache2/error.log').size
       @@counter=1;
    end # <- this line is where the warning points to
   end


# main execution
em = ErrorMonitor.new()
while true
    em.process
    sleep 10
end
```

Comment: Currently `@@counter` is an int, but you're using it as a boolean. Likewise you don't need the `@@` Class variable decorator--`@counter`, `@previous_size`, will do--if you only have one ErrorMonitor object. Likewise, `@new_size` doesn't need to persist so `new_size` would work.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
if condition
  # …
else
  # …
end
```

not

```
if condition
  # …
end
else
  # …
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the else block is not part of an if statement. Am I correct in assuming you want it to provide an alternative path when `if @@counter > 0` is false? If so, get rid of the `end` that's on the line above the else, e.g.:

```
if @@Counter > 0
    # ... processing ...
else
    # ... alternative processing ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: `else` is the warning is intended as below:

```
def my_method
  if rand >= 0.5
    raise
  end
rescue
  puts "ERROR!!!"
else
  puts "Cool"
end
```

If you prematurely close the `if` statement, it's likely that the `else` will be interpreted as the `else` in the code above.  So having an `else` statement without the `rescue` is useless, because you can simply write your method like this:

```
def my_method
  if rand >= 0.5
    raise
  end
  puts "Cool"
end
```

Either `rescue` is executed, or  `else` is executed, never both.

Answer (score 0):

This error message appeared to me when I had an extra `do` keyword in an `if` clause. Something like this:

```
if condition do
  # …
else
  # …
end
```

So, make sure you don't have a reserved word `do` in some `if` clause.

```
if condition
  # …
else
  # …
end
```